# Calculate $Var(125 \times 10^6t - S_{5000t})$

Tags: probability-theory, variance

> Assume that $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ with $X_i$ being i.i.d. and $E[X_1] = 25000$ and $V[X_1] = 2500$. Define $Y(t) = 125 \times 10^6t - S_{5000t}$ for $t \in \Bbb N$.

Calculating $E[Y(t)]$ is pretty easy, but I don't see how to calculate $Var[Y(t)]$. I would have started like this:

$Var(125 \times 10^6t - S_{5000t}) = Var(125 \times 10^6t) - Var(S_{5000t}) = 0 - Var(S_{5000t}),$ which obviously yields a negative value.

Where am I mistaken here?

Comment: $$Var(X-Y) \neq Var(X) - Var(Y)$$
I'd recommend starting from first principles and trying to derive the correct equality.

Comment: Yes, it'*s actually only $Var(S_{5000t})$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\mathbf{Var}(a+bX) = b^2\mathbf{Var}(X^2)$$
it follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Var}(125 \times 10^6t - S_{5000t}) &= (-1)^2\mathbf{Var}(S_{5000t}).
\end{align}

Comment: But you can't compute $E[S^2_{5000t}]$, can you?

Comment: I don't think that your solution is correct. By using $Var(aX + b) = a^2Var(X)$, you receive $Var(Y(T)) = Var(S_{5000t})$, which allows me to use $Var(X_1) = 2500$.

Comment: @Borol I didn't know you were aware of this rule. The previous answer was correct, but using this result it is much simpler.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! :)